# How to update or delete last value entered in PostgreSQL, using Python?

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, sql-update

I am inserting data in PostgreSQL, but sometimes I need to update the entered value. I did the following to get the last entered value, but not sure how to update it.

```
def add_data(w1,w2):
    conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='Aspentiment' user='postgres' password='pwd'"
    conn=psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    foo= "INSERT INTO proccessing.aspects(aspects_name,sentiments) VALUES('%s','%s')" %(w1,w2)
    cursor.execute(foo)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def add_Neg_data(w1): 
    conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='Aspentiment' user='postgres' password='pwd'"
    conn=psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
    cursor = conn.cursor()    
    cursor.execute("SELECT aspects_name, sentiments FROM proccessing.aspects")
    bgrow = cursor.fetchall()[-1]
    row = bgrow[1]
    print(row)
    foo= "INSERT INTO proccessing.aspects(aspects_name,sentiments) VALUES('%s','%s')" %(w1)
    cursor.execute(foo)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

and then at some point I use both functions like

```
add_data(word1,word2)
```

In these cases I need to update the entered word2, so I want to use another function to update like

```
add_Neg_data(word1,new_word)
```

So far I get the last word entered but don't know how to update the word.
Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't answer your specific question relative to Python, I am hopeful it will give you enough pieces to point you in the right direction.  Unfortunately, I don't know Python.  I do speak Perl, which in spite of being anti-Python (from what I am told), I am also told it's notionally similar.

Essentially, I think what you want is the `returning` clause, which allows an insert or update statement to return a value back to the issuer.

Assuming your table looks like this:

```
create table proccessing.aspects (
  id serial,
  aspects_name text,
  sentiments text
);
```

Where your inserts are creating some form of surrogate key (I assume this to be the case, otherwise I have no idea how to tackle your problem) this means your inserts will result in the auto-generation of an `id` value.

The following statement would not only perform the insert but also return back the value of `id`:

```
insert into proccessing.aspects
(aspects_name,sentiments)
values
(:ASPECTS, :SENTIMENTS)
returning id
```

Again, I don't speak Python, but in C# there are essentially three basic ways to execute a command:

```
command.ExecuteDataReader();   -- used for reading rows from a query
command.ExcecuteNonQuery();    -- execute a SQL command that is not a select
command.ExecuteScalar();
```

I'm hopeful your DB adapter is similar.  In this case, we would use the last one, `ExecuteScalar`, which would return an object of the resulting `id`.  It can also be used (more commonly than this example, in fact) when you are guaranteed to get a single value from a query, such as a `select count (*) from whatever`.

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

If it helps, the Perl equivalent to this is `selectrow_array`.

```
my ($id) = $dbh->selectrow_array($aspects, $sentiments);
```

Again, I wish I had more Python-specific info for you, but the bottom line is assuming you have a surrogate key of some type that is populated via `serial`, a trigger, or a default value, I think what you want is the `returning` clause.

From there, you should be able to do a normal update.

```
update proccessing.aspects
set
  aspects_name = :ASPECTS,
  sentiments = :SENTIMENTS
where
  id = :ID
```